# Is there a stable and non-toxic hydro-nitrogen-oxygen compound that's liquid in room temperature?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, fuel

Is there a stable (i.e. does not turn into other substance when stored in a bottle exposed to the elements  or explode/combust spontaneously or under mechanical impact) compound that contains just $\mathrm{N}$, $\mathrm{H}$ and $\mathrm{O}$ but *no* $\mathrm{C}$ and is (a) either liquid or can exist as a high concentration ($80\%+$) water solution at the range of $-50\,{}^\circ\mathrm{C}\sim+70\,{}^\circ\mathrm{C}$ and (b) preferably non-toxic (c) combustible, but this seems to be usually implicit from its composition?

(Aside from $\mathrm{N}\mathrm{H}_3$, $\mathrm{N}_2\mathrm{H}_4$, $\mathrm{H}\mathrm{N}\mathrm{O}_3$, or $\mathrm{N}\mathrm{H}_4\mathrm{N}\mathrm{O}_3$ that is.)

Comment: Why there is an [organic-chemistry] tag if you don't want to look into C-containing compounds?! Also, since there is [fuel] tag, does it mean it also should be a high-energy material?

Comment: @andselisk the high-energy part is not a must.

Comment: How about [ammonium nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammonium_nitrate) water solution or just [nitric acid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitric_acid)?

Comment: @andselisk That seems to be explosive? The other one is unstable stored too.

Comment: Hydroxylamine in water - not explosive but there toxicity issues

Comment: Ammonium nitrate is not an explosive on its own, it's a *component* of explosives. Nitric acid is unstable in a sense that concentrated solution is light-sensitive and is a strong oxidant. I'm afraid that's the best you can get. Probably it would be beneficial if you share what do you need the stuff for.

Comment: @andselisk I'm just curious if there could exist a non-lh2, non-hydrazine jet/rocket fuel that produces absolutely no soot whatsoever. Energy density doesn't matter as long as it is not orders of magnitudes lower than kerosene.